# Populating dropdown list with SQL in Visual Studio but using a textbox in query

Tags: sql, .net, visual-studio

I've been trying to populate a dropdown list in visual studio .net but whenever I try to use a textbox in my query, I've been using the configure the select statement wizard in visual studio and am given errors when try to use a text box in the sql select command or am given empty fields when I test query.

```
         <table class="auto-style1">
 <tr>
     <td class="auto-style1"></td>
       <td class="auto-style2">
           Select Class:</td>
            <td class="auto-style1">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="ClassName" DataValueField="ClassName"></asp:DropDownList>



                     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [ClassName] FROM [Classroom] WHERE ([TeacherUsername] = @TeacherUsername)">
                         <SelectParameters>
                          <asp:FormParameter FormField="TextBox1.Text" Name="TeacherUsername" Type="String" />
                           </SelectParameters>
                        </asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </td>
                    <td class="auto-style1">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

So can anyone help me include my textbox in my sql select query, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your SelectCommand remove the where clause of the TeacherUsername and add filter to it:

`SelectCommand="SELECT [ClassName] FROM [Classroom]" FilterExpression="TeacherUsername= '{0}'"`

Comment: I've tried this method, but still no values appear from the drop down menu, I've also tried deleting the parameter lines of code but still doesn't help.